# Como listar a ultima mensagem de todas as conversas

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

Estou criando um chat no android studio, logo preciso listar a ultima mensagem entre o utilizador do chat e seus contatos, independente dele ter enviado ou recebido a ultima mensagem.

Fiz o select abaixo no `mysql` e esta funcionando, mas no `sqlite` retorna erro próximo ao union, (não entendo muito da sintaxe do `sqlite`)

Código abaixo utilizando a variável 7

```
SELECT mensagens.* FROM mensagens JOIN (
    SELECT user, MAX(id) m FROM (
        (SELECT id, id_user user, data FROM mensagens WHERE contact_user=7) 
        UNION 
        (SELECT id, contact_user user, data FROM mensagens WHERE id_user=7)
    ) t1 GROUP BY user
) t2 ON ((contact_user=7 AND id_user=user) OR (contact_user=user AND id_user=7)) 
AND (id = m) ORDER BY id DESC
```

Minha tabela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado do select

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual a mensagem de erro?

Comment: No mysql funciona perfeitamente, no sqlite do Android retorna erro próximo ao union

Comment: Só isso? Tenta executar cada parte do `union` separadamente. Não tenho certeza se para por alias em coluna é necessário por `AS alias` no sqlite, mas isso me saltou à vista

Comment: De qualquer sorte, é viável fazer uma consulta equivalente sem `union`, usando um `or` na cláusula `where` e um `case` no `select`. Minha experiência diz que remover essa união pode tornar a consulta mais leve, caso ela esteja sendo executado de maneira repetida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o Jefferson Quesado sugeriu, a consulta fica mais simples usando um case:

```
SELECT mensagens.* FROM mensagens JOIN (
    SELECT 
      (case when id_user=7 then contact_user
        when contact_user=7 then id_user
       end) user
      , MAX(id) m 
    FROM mensagens 
    WHERE id_user=7 or contact_user=7
    GROUP BY user
) t1 ON id = m 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

[Exemplo funcionando no SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/3fcdce/1/0) com SQLite (SQL.js).

Comment: Muito obrigado! funcionou perfeitamente, já estava pensando em fazer 2 consultas no db, para chegar ao resultado, mas vc me salvou! vlw mesmo!

Answer (score 0):

Para obter o resultado pretendido para apenas um utilizador em especifico pode ser utilizado:

```
SELECT * FROM mensagens WHERE id_user=7 OR contact_user=7 ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Dessa forma, ele retorna a última mensagem que eu enviei e também a última mensagem que eu recebi de cada conversa

Comment: @JulioAntonini Não... Testou o código?

Comment: Essa foi minha primeira ideia, quando precisei, mas vi q não daria certo, mas muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @JulioAntonini Acho que o meu comentário não foi muito esclarecedor: só devolve a última mensagem (enviada ou recebida). `LIMIT 1` só devolve 1 resultado!

Comment: a sim com o limite ele retorna apenas 1 resultado o ultimo, porem podem existir ilimitadas conversas, ai teria que fazer 2 selects para pegar a ultima mensagem de cada conversa